# How to make tableview delegates disappear behind margins / headers?

Tags: python, qml, pyside2

After adding a custom header to a tableview in qml, I need to make the delegate items in the table disappear as they scroll up to the bottom of the header.

With the header in place, I've also added a topMargin to the tableview so that the header is above the delegates when the table is first drawn. When the table is scrolled, the delegate items scroll behind and above the header before they disappear.

I've tried adjusting the visible and opacity parameters of the delegate based on their position relative to the header, but it appears there is no signal triggering the position values to be re-evaluated. They continue to scroll up past the header without disappearing.

Therefore, I've also tried to use the onMovementEnded function within TableView to force the values to refresh when the table stops scrolling. However, it is not picking up the id of the delegate.

**QML**

*TableView with header definition*

```
TableView {
    id: xyztable
    columnWidthProvider: function (column) { return width / columns; }
    rowHeightProvider: function (column) { return 20; }
    topMargin: columnsHeader.height + 20
    Layout.rowSpan: 4
    Layout.fillHeight: true

    model: XYZTableModel
    width: 350
    boundsMovement: Flickable.StopAtBounds
    boundsBehavior: Flickable.DragOverBounds
    opacity: Math.max(0.5, 1.0 - Math.abs(verticalOvershoot) / height)

    delegate: CustomComp.XYZTableDelegate {
        id: localdelegate
        implicitWidth: parent.width / xyztable.columns
        implicitHeight: 20
    }

    Rectangle { // mask the headers
        id: columnsHeader
        z: 2
        color: "#222222"
        y: xyztable.contentY - 20
        x: xyztable.contentX
        width: xyztable.width
        height: 30
    }

    Row { // create header content
        id: columnsHeaderContent
        y: xyztable.contentY
        z: 3
        Repeater {
            model: xyztable.columns > 0 ? xyztable.columns : 1
            Label {
                width: xyztable.columnWidthProvider(modelData)
                height: xyztable.rowHeightProvider(modelData) * 2
                text: XYZTableModel.headerData(modelData, Qt.Horizontal)
                color: 'white'
                font.pixelSize: 15
                padding: 10
                verticalAlignment: Text.AlignVCenter
                horizontalAlignment: Text.AlignHCenter

                background: Rectangle { color: "#333333" }
            }
        }
    }

    ScrollIndicator.horizontal: ScrollIndicator { }
    ScrollIndicator.vertical: ScrollIndicator { }
}
```

*Adjust visible within delegate*

```
delegate: CustomComp.XYZTableDelegate {
    id: localdelegate
    implicitWidth: parent.width / xyztable.columns
    implicitHeight: 20
    visible: localdelegate.mapToItem(columnsHeader, 0, y).y < columnsHeader.height ? false : true
}
```

*Adjust visible onMovementEnded*

```
onMovementEnded: {
    localdelegate.visible = localdelegate.mapToItem(columnsHeader, 0, localdelegate.y).y < columnsHeader.height ? false : true
}
```

I expected that the delegates would disappear after they passed the bottom of the header during scrolling. However, they still scrolled up past the header. While adjusting the visible parameter within delegate, I did see the table get shifted downwards by about 6 delegate heights when the table was scrolled back to its original position.

Answer (score 0):

After an extensive effort, I still hadn't found a way to turn the visibility of the table delegates to false as they moved past the bottom of the header. The closest I got was adjusting their values within the TabelView onMovementEnded handler by looping through the children of the TableView.contentItem.children. However, the visible parameter would only be changed when the table stopped moving.

Instead, I moved away from trying to manipulate the delegates, and simply began adjusting the header position. I moved the header a negative y value from the tableView.contentY location. Then I adjusted the topMargin value accordingly. This results in a header shifted far enough beyond the top of the flickable content that the content does not breech the top of the header when scrolling.

```
import QtQuick 2.12
import QtQuick.Controls 2.12

TableView {
    id: tableView

    property var yposition: 20

    columnWidthProvider: function (column) { return width / columns; }
    rowHeightProvider: function (column) { return 20; }
    topMargin: columnsHeaderContent.height - yposition

    boundsMovement: Flickable.StopAtBounds
    boundsBehavior: Flickable.DragOverBounds
    opacity: Math.max(0.5, 1.0 - Math.abs(verticalOvershoot) / height)

    Row { // create header content
        id: columnsHeaderContent
        y: tableView.contentY - tableView.yposition
        z: 2
        height: tableView.rowHeightProvider(modelData) * 2
        Repeater {
            model: tableView.columns > 0 ? tableView.columns : 1
            Rectangle {
                width: tableView.columnWidthProvider(modelData)
                height: tableView.rowHeightProvider(modelData) * 2
                Label {
                    id: columnsHeaderLabel
                    z: 1
                    width: tableView.columnWidthProvider(modelData)
                    height: tableView.rowHeightProvider(modelData) * 2
                    text: tableView.model.headerData(modelData, Qt.Horizontal)
                    color: 'white'
                    font.pixelSize: 15
                    padding: 10
                    verticalAlignment: Text.AlignVCenter
                    horizontalAlignment: Text.AlignHCenter

                    background: Rectangle { color: "#2A2C35" }
                }

                Rectangle {
                    color: "#000000"
                    y: tableView.rowHeightProvider(modelData) * 2 - 5
                    z: 2
                    height: 5
                    width: parent.width
                }
            }
        }
    }

    ScrollIndicator.horizontal: ScrollIndicator { }
    ScrollIndicator.vertical: ScrollIndicator { }
}
```